# django allauth login test can't login correctly

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a login test for django allauth but although the app works correctly and I can login, when I write a login test it fails to login correctly and I get an assertion error `Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
302 != 200` because of a validation error `'The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct'

(currently test_login fails but the other two tests pass)

Looking at the tests in django all-auth here:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/tests.py
I can see that they also create an EmailAddress object when testing login - I'm not sure why or if this is needed?

```
class TestLoginView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.username = "test@test.com"
        self.password = "password"
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(self.username, self.password)
        # EmailAddress.objects.create(user=user, email=self.username, primary=True, verified=True)

    def test_login(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse(
            settings.LOGIN_URL), {"login": self.username, "password": self.password}
        )
        self.assertRedirects(response, settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, fetch_redirect_response=False)

    def test_wrong_login(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse(
            settings.LOGIN_URL), {"login": "bad@login.com", "password": "wrong"}
        )
        validation_error = 'The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct'
        assert validation_error in response.content.decode('utf-8')

    def test_redirect_when_authenticated(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        resp = self.client.get(reverse(settings.LOGIN_URL))
        url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL + '/' + self.username + '/' + 'detail'
        self.assertRedirects(resp, url, fetch_redirect_response=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the user creation to using keyword args fixed it, ie:

```
self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username=self.username, password=self.password)
```

alternatively you can drop the seperate Email model creation too and just do

```
get_user_model().objects.create_user(username=username,  email=username, password=password)
```